# insert if not exist from arraylist<vector>

Tags: java, sql

Good evening 
i have problem about a query of insert if not exist i have do it in another query and it worked
but now i have an array of class java Service
so i want test about the id : VLAN
because i execut every time and i want that not insert many time if it exist already on table sql

This is my query but they give me an error about it

```
for(Service srv:service){
        srvDataLst.add(srv.getvlan());

PreparedStatement pst=conn.prepareStatement(
        "INSERT INTO tout (VLAN,client,JR,vrf,address) "
        + "VALUES(?,?,?,?,?) SELECT DISTINCT "
        + "'"+srv.getvlan()+"' FROM dual WHERE NOT EXISTS("
        + "SELECT * FROM tout WHERE 'VLAN'='"+srv.getvlan()+"') ");
        pst.setInt(1,srv.getvlan());    
        pst.setString(2,convertNullToEmptyString(srv.getdesc()));
    pst.setString(3,convertNullToEmptyString(srv.getjr()));
    pst.setString(4,convertNullToEmptyString(srv.getvrf()));
    pst.setString(5,convertNullToEmptyString(srv.getaddress()));
    pst.executeUpdate();
```

Thank you for help

The error is:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an 
error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your 
MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
'SELECT DISTINCT '20' FROM dual WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM tout 
WHERE 'VLAN'=' at line 1
```

Comment: "_but they give me an error about it_" We need more details on that...

Comment: i have class java Service contains the same data on tables sql so i do test it stocked the data in Service i do the loop and i insert this data in table sql but when i execut another tim it will be a repetition so i want add just the data that's not inserted in table

Comment: Just a question: what are the chances of the insert failing? If it is low, just let it be and drop the whole `where not exists` -- especially if your `VLAN` parameter is a primary key. It is faster to catch the exception. What is more, why do you inject `srv.getvlan()` as a string in this `not exists` clause? This is a potential SQL injection... Which is not really understandable since the rest of your query does use parameters!

Comment: But it gives me error : com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT DISTINCT '20' FROM dual WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM tout WHERE 'VLAN'=' at line 1

Comment: no Vlan just the first column it's not a primary key and i use this query in another code it worked but without this part table() Values()

Comment: i used here it worked : ("INSERT INTO router\n" +
"SELECT DISTINCT '"+jTextField1.getText()+"','"+jTextField2.getText()+"','2700' \n" +
"FROM dual\n" +
"WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM router WHERE `edge01` = '"+jTextField1.getText()+"' AND `edge02` = '"+jTextField2.getText()+"')");

Comment: @cisco.nat: read [xkcd.com/327/](http://xkcd.com/327/) !!!

Comment: yes i read that and many documents but i don't know how can i resolv this because i use it in another code and it worked

Answer (score 0):

It's either `insert into ... values(...)` or `insert into ... select ...`, you can't use both in the same statement.